# can't remove hidden characters in text?

Tags: python

```
<pre>str_1 = u"tác toàn diện giữa Việt Nam và Ukraine ."
str_2 = u"tác toàn diện giữa Việt Nam và Ukraine ."
for w in str_1.split():
    for w1 in str_2.split():
        if w == w1:
            print(w)
</pre>
```

output:

```
Nam
Ukraine
.
```

I copied the string str_1 from an online newspaper.

str_2 is the sentence that I typed.

I guess that str_1 contain hidden characters, because when I compare its, the output showed that some words are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to encode the two strings as utf8:

```
str_1 = u"tác toàn diện giữa Việt Nam và Ukraine ."
str_2 = u"tác toàn diện giữa Việt Nam và Ukraine ."
print(str_1.encode('utf8'))
>> b'ta\xcc\x81c toa\xcc\x80n di\xc3\xaa\xcc\xa3n gi\xc6\xb0\xcc\x83a Vi\xc3\xaa\xcc\xa3t Nam va\xcc\x80 Ukraine .'
print(str_2.encode('utf8'))
>> b't\xc3\xa1c to\xc3\xa0n di\xe1\xbb\x87n gi\xe1\xbb\xafa Vi\xe1\xbb\x87t Nam v\xc3\xa0 Ukraine .'
```

You can see that it in fact the two strings are different. If you look closely, the different between "diện" in str_1 and str_2, is that in str_1 there is a small dot under the n and in str_2 there is a small dot under the e

Comment: Yeah, Thank you for your help, how can I normalize str_1 to str_2?

Comment: If you import the `unidecode` package, then if you do `str_1_n = unidecode.unidecode(str_1)` and `str_2_n = unidecode.unidecode(str_2)` then `str_1_n` and `str_2_n` should be equal.

Comment: I have tried using unidecode for str_1 and str_2, it became the same but another issue appeared , the accent in text was be removed.